# NSDateFormatter Issue with iOS6?

Tags: iphone, ios6, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a date string like 2012/10/11 21:46:31 +0000

And I have tried almost maximum number of combinations but everytime I am getting NSDate as null.

```
NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[fmt setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *fromDate = [fmt dateFromString:fromDateString];
```

I am using iOS6

where `fromDateString= 2012/10/11 21:46:31 +0000`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following (include the timezone string):

```
NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[fmt setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *fromDate = [fmt dateFromString:@"2012/10/11 21:46:31 +0000"];
```